# A soft question from ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Suppose we want to solve the following ordinary equation
$$(-\partial_x^2+W[f(x)])\psi(x)=0$$
within the range $x\in[-T,T]$ for a large number T and
with the following boundary conditions
$$\psi(-T)=0,\ \partial_{x}\psi(x)|_{-T}=1.$$

Now suppose for a particular function $f(x)=f_1(x)$, I have obtained a solution $\psi_1(x)$. My question is, for another function $f_2(x)$ which is very close to $f_1(x)$, what is the relation between the solution $\psi_2(x)$ and $\psi_1(x)$? Is there any mathematical theory (on ODE or operator theory) which aims to solve this kind of question?

I would really appreciate for your information. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's similar to the dependence on initial conditions. You might try Coddington and Levinson.

Comment: What is $W[f(x)]$? Regarding your question, yes, solutions of IVPs depend continuously (usually even smoothly) on parameters (I just googled [lecture notes](https://math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec6.pdf)), you can consult any good textbook on ODEs.  In your case, see also [How to prove that a parametrized linear differential equation solution induces a lipschitz function with respect to the parameter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747335/how-to-prove-that-a-parametrized-linear-differential-equation-solution-induces-a).